# Is there an ExampleMatcher with not equals condition

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am working with spring data jpa, I would like to know in QueryByExample(QBE) can i get all the records (where colum value not equals 'XXX')

I have seen ExampleMatcher , but couldnt find anything like not equals

```
        Employee filterBy = new Employee();
        filterBy.setLastName("ar"); 

        //Filter - ignore case search and contains 
        ExampleMatcher matcher = ExampleMatcher.matching()     
                  .withStringMatcher(StringMatcher.CONTAINING)   // Match string containing pattern   
                  .withIgnoreCase();                 // ignore case sensitivity 

        example = Example.of(filterBy, matcher);
```

The above code gets all the records where lastname is ar, but i am looking for lastname should not be "ar".
Is there any other ExampleMatcher ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
BizExceptionConfig condition = configRequestPair.getCondition();
ExampleMatcher exampleMatcher = ExampleMatcher.matching()
        .withMatcher("appCode", startsWith())
        .withMatcher("name", startsWith())
        .withMatcher("code", startsWith());

if(Objects.isNull(condition.getLifecycle())){
    condition.setLifecycle(LifeCycle.DELETE.getCode());
    HashMap<String, Integer> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("$ne", LifeCycle.DELETE.getCode());
    exampleMatcher = exampleMatcher.withTransformer("lifecycle", (obj) -> Optional.of(params));
}
Example<BizExceptionConfig> example = Example.of(condition, exampleMatcher);
Page<BizExceptionConfig> pageRecord = bizExcConfigRepository.findAll(example, PageUtil.toPageRequest(configRequestPair.getPage()));`enter code here`
```

This problem can be solved by "withTransformer". JPA is rather limited,
so I suggest using Mongotmpl. I hope it can help you

Comment: This answer seems correct but I cannot get it to work, would you please adapt it to the example code provided in the question so that will become more usable?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem could be solved with QBE by using `REGEX` as StringMatcher and the solution would look like the following:

```java
Employee filterBy = new Employee();
filterBy.setLastName("ar");
filterBy.setLastName(String.format("^(?!.*$1$).*$", Pattern.quote(filterBy.getLastName())));
//filterBy.setLastName(String.format(".*(?<!$1)$", Pattern.quote(filterBy.getLastName())));  // this would be another alternative
ExampleMatcher matcher = ExampleMatcher.matching()
    .withStringMatcher(StringMatcher.REGEX)   // Match string containing pattern   
                  .withIgnoreCase();                 // ignore case sensitivity
Example example = Example.of(filterBy, matcher);
```

Unfortunately, even though the developer would at first think that Regular Expressions are supported (as there exists aforementioned enum constant), Spring actually currently doesn't support them - and according to the discussion of the related Jira issue, it never won't: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-944